# Deliver on promise

Tags: usage

Is 'deliver on promise' an idiomatic phrase?

If it is so, how do native use it?

If it's possible, feel free to provide an example in the sentence

Comment: Deliver on his/her promise = do what he/she has promised to do.

Comment: Is it frequent enough to use it in an everyday language?

Comment: Yes - mainly with regard to providing a service or something important. "Let us hope the government will deliver on its election promises."

Comment: You might also be interested in the advice "to under promise and over deliver" which is quite a common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

You can [*deliver on **a** promise*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deliver%20on%20a%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdeliver%20on%20a%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20certain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20promise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20date%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20contract%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20convenient%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20particular%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20specified%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20firm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20regular%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cdeliver%20on%20a%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20certain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20promise%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20date%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20contract%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20convenient%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20particular%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20specified%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20firm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdeliver%20on%20a%20regular%3B%2Cc0) (or *a commitment, an undertaking, a contract,...*)...

[image: screenshot of Google NGrams showing "deliver on a promise" is far more common than other completions of "deliver on a..."]

...just as you can intransitively...

> [**deliver**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliver) - to produce the promised, desired, or expected results
> = COME THROUGH [WITH]
> Example usages:
> *can't deliver on all these promises*
> *a hitter who can deliver in the clutch*

Note that without the preposition *(deliver **on**)*, the "object" would be the *actual* "thing" delivered - so *He delivered the contract* simply means he produced the contract (or took it to wherever it was supposed to go), whereas *He delivered **on** the contract* means he made sure that everything specified in the contract was in fact done.